# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I have a problem with unwrapping and not understand this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`.
```

All that i have found help me not onward. In the first ViewController i have this code

```
var everypicture = [EveryPicture] ()
```

and I present the delegate of the first ViewController to the SecondViewController:

```
var delegate: FirstViewController?`
```

in the Segue. Then i get the every picture from the delegate and get the count:

```
let piccount = delegate?.everypicture.count
print("\(piccount!)")`
```

but its comes the error. What make I wrong and what does the error mean ? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

So as I understand the error message says that when it tried to unwrap some value it got nil object. Unwrapping operation - getting from optional value real one. In code that you posted I can see only once this operation

```
print("\(piccount!)")
```

So picccount variable is nil and using operator "!" you tried to unwrap it by saying "Man that is not nil, be sure" but it is.

To find where i the problem set stop execution ob this line

```
let pic count = delegate?.everypicture.count
```

and check if:

1) delegate is nil

2) array is nil (it shouldn't be but still it's not so hard to check)

Hope it helped.

Comment: His array can't be `nil` the way it's declared. It's either empty or has a value. Most likely the delegate is nil and he's just trying things out without reading the documentations or doing a proper tutorial.

Comment: my delegate was nil but i present the delegate in the segue of the FirstViewController `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "EveryPhotoSegue" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! EverydayController
            vc.delegate = self}}`  EverydayController is my SecondViewController.

Comment: No sorry , the delegate must be nil or ? So wenn i have unwrap piccount `print("\(piccount!)")` then it´s comes the error and wenn i not unwrap piccoutn `print("\(piccount)")` then it´s nil.

Comment: Yes, because you haven't set delegate. If delegate is not seted - than it will be nil and calling method to nil instance will return nil. Thats why your instance is nil. If you unwrapping nil value with operator "!" that it will cause exception, if you omit this operation than nil will be converted to String "nil". If having nil delegate value is fine for your code logic than you should perform checking if it's nil or not and than perform action. But if delegate always shouldn't be nil that you should check through the code where you are setting delegate and why it's not seted in the end.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never assigning a value to `delegate`. You're just defining its type as `FirstViewController?`. You need to assign an instance of that class. `piccount` becomes an optional because `delegate` itself was an optional. Force-unwrapping `piccount` is incorrect (because `delegate` was nil); use an `if let` instead.